# Firefox Nightly won't update

Tags: firefox, ppa

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I recently noticed that Firefox Nightly was running on version 61 from March, while the latest is version 64 from August. I use the extra ppa and tried to manually update the browser

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox-trunk
```

But I always get

```
firefox-trunk is already the newest version (61.0~a1~hg20180331r410852-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~umd1).
```

Launch pad shows that the latest available version is actually 63. What am I doing wrong and how can I update my browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you visit https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages, you'll see the following image as of today indicating **build failures** for xenial, bionic, and cosmic:

[image: Build failure]

I'm sure you're aware that nightly builds aren't advisable for regular use. But if you want, you can download builds directly from https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/ for [64-bit](https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-nightly-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=en-US) or [32-bit](https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-nightly-latest-ssl&os=linux&lang=en-US) and follow http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=3041682 where other users of nightly and beta post their observations and report bugs they encounter and bugs they file.

[image: Firefox 64 - nightly]

This build will update automatically.